# Best way to loop through this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an api call for bitcoin returning this aray when i use `print_r()`, what would be the best way to loop through it so that i can use the data to generate a table or chart?

```
[{"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301982430, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.62}, 
{"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301982430, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.62}, 
{"volume": 31, "timestamp": 1301981474, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.64}, 
{"volume": 8.592, "timestamp": 1301981466, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6401}, 
{"volume": 10.89, "timestamp": 1301981466, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6401}, 
{"volume": 9.61, "timestamp": 1301981066, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641},
{"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301981058, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}, 
{"volume": 21.654, "timestamp": 1301981058, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641},
{"volume": 2E+1, "timestamp": 1301980388, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6729}, 
{"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301980373, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}]
```

Comment: man you scate the hell outta me with your array .. please try to make more understable - also could you explain what kinda data-grid you are planning to make.

Comment: Am planning to create a graph using google charts api... so that people could understand the trend of bitcoin for last 30 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first convert this [**JSON**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSON) string to a PHP array using [**`json_decode()`**](http://fr.php.net/json_decode) :

```
$str = '[{"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301982430, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.62}, {"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301982430, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.62}, {"volume": 31, "timestamp": 1301981474, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.64}, {"volume": 8.592, "timestamp": 1301981466, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6401}, {"volume": 10.89, "timestamp": 1301981466, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6401}, {"volume": 9.61, "timestamp": 1301981066, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}, {"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301981058, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}, {"volume": 21.654, "timestamp": 1301981058, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}, {"volume": 2E+1, "timestamp": 1301980388, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.6729}, {"volume": 1E+1, "timestamp": 1301980373, "symbol": "mtgoxUSD", "price": 0.641}]';
$data = json_decode($str);
```

And, then, the simplest way to iterate over those data would be with a [**`foreach`**][3] loop :

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "{$item->volume} - {$item->timestamp} - {$item->symbol} - {$item->price} <br />";
}
```

Which would get you something like this :

```
10 - 1301982430 - mtgoxUSD - 0.62
10 - 1301982430 - mtgoxUSD - 0.62
31 - 1301981474 - mtgoxUSD - 0.64
8.592 - 1301981466 - mtgoxUSD - 0.6401
10.89 - 1301981466 - mtgoxUSD - 0.6401
9.61 - 1301981066 - mtgoxUSD - 0.641
10 - 1301981058 - mtgoxUSD - 0.641
21.654 - 1301981058 - mtgoxUSD - 0.641
20 - 1301980388 - mtgoxUSD - 0.6729
10 - 1301980373 - mtgoxUSD - 0.641
```

Answer (score 1):

Array looks like the json encoded you have to decode it with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$array=json_decode($array,true);
```

and use foreach loop to iterate through array

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key." has the value ".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

decode it into an normal array:

```
$str = json_decode($string);
```